# substring-after and substring-before using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would extract using Xslt 1.0 the string between col4 and col4, col5 and col5, col6 and col6, col8 and col8.

This is my XML:

```
<NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
    <LIGHT_EXCEPTION>col4[#Al Fl WGW 17s[$col4col518col5col6[#W 24;G 18[$col6col8[#W 1[$ - 3 - [#G 1[$ - 3- [#W 1[$ - 8;[#P[$col8</LIGHT_EXCEPTION>
</NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
```

Request:I would divide: from col 4 to col4 - from col5 to col5 - from col6 to col6 - from col8 to col8;

And Have this result:
[#Al Fl WGW 17s[$   <====This is Col 4
18       <=====this is Col5
[#W 24;G 18[$   <====This is Col6
[#W 1[$ - 3 - [#G 1[$ - 3- [#W 1[$ - 8;[#P[$ <====This is Col8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(LIGHT_EXCEPTION, 'col4'), 'col4')"/>
```

etc.